# Disable list if option selected

Tags: vbscript, hta

My code is partially working. The list gets disabled but it's not catching that I have selected "product1" and then enables the list. Anything else chosen should disable the list completely. List with ID product. So I guess it's something with my syntax for the option selected, not sure if thats the correct way to write it.

**VBScript**

```vb
'Disables or enables list based on selection
Function enabler()
    For Each opt In document.GetElementByID("customer").Options
        If opt.Selected = "product1" Then
          document.GetElementByID("product").Disabled = False
        Else
          document.GetElementByID("product").Disabled = True
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

**HTA**

```html
...
<select size="5" id="product" name="ListboxUserRole" onChange="SaveListboxUserRoleValue">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">product1</option>
    <option value="2">product2</option>
    <option value="3">product3</option>
...
<select size="5" id="customer" name="ListboxCustomer" onChange="SaveListboxCustomerValue" value="1">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">customer1</option>
    <option value="2">customer2</option>
    <option value="3">customer3</option>
    <option value="4">customer4</option>
...
```

Comment: Can you update with your full hta code?

Comment: Its very big, but i am calling the function on body load. <body onload="enabler()">

Comment: So, you want to disable the whole `product` list when you select `product1` from the `customer` list, right?

Comment: There is no element with the id `customer` in the HTML snippet you posted. Please update your question with a [mcve] so we can reproduce and analyze the problem.

Comment: Correct Christos :)

Comment: Still doesn't make sense. There is no option labeled `product1` in the element with the ID `customer`. What do you want enabled/disabled under which exact conditions?

Comment: There is some mess with lists, could you please elaborate what is the list to select from, and what is the list to disable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get it right, you need to enable the `customer` select when `product1` is selected in `product` select, and disable if any other.

**First of all**, `product` select change event is linked to `SaveListboxCustomerValue()`. `customer` select disabling should be processed within `SaveListboxCustomerValue()`, replace `<body onload="enabler()">` with just `<body>`.

**IMO better to rework the algorithm** to use the `selectedIndex` property of the `product` select object, the `enabler()` is not necessary then. Remove `enabler()`, and make changes to `SaveListboxCustomerValue()`:

```
Sub SaveListboxCustomerValue()

    ' enable customer if the first item in product selected
    customer.disabled = product.selectedIndex <> 0

    ' the rest part of the code

End Sub
```

**Otherwise, if you want to keep** the `enabler()`, then read about [Option Object Properties](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_option.asp). The condition you currently have always returns `False`, since boolean value never equals the string `"product1"`. The code should be like this:

```
Sub enabler()

    Dim opt
    Dim match

    For Each opt In product.options
        match = opt.selected And opt.label = "product1"
        If match Then Exit For
    Next
    customer.disabled = Not match

End Sub
```

`enabler()` should be called on `customer` change, add call to it:

```
Sub SaveListboxCustomerValue()

    enabler()

    ' the rest part of the code

End Sub
```

Comment: Still disables the list no matter what. Selected product 1 but still disabled.

Comment: @Avean I added the alternative solution.

Comment: really nice :) That did the trick. But if i change back to product1 again it doesnt enable the list again. Right now product1 selection makes the list active, all other options deactivated. All good. But if i go back to product1 again, the list is still deactivated. Any tips?

Comment: @Avean are you using the 1st or the 2nd option from the answer?

Comment: @omegatstripes oh sorry, second :)

Comment: @Avean why not to try the 1st one then?

Comment: Worked like a charm that way :) Thank you so much.